# iOS MSAL Library flagged for insecure cryptographic encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, azure-ad-msal

I'm working with the [Microsoft Authentication Library for iOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/tree/master#configuring-msal). It is being flagged by a Microfocus Fortify scan for the following vulnerability. I need to understand two things:

1. What encryption mode is this using with AES 128 (CBC, ECB, GCM, etc) ?
2. How and where is the Initialized Vector (key) being generated? If it's null in this case, I saw another post discussing the [NULL key scenario for CCCrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014292/cccrypt-decrypting-in-aes-cbc-works-even-without-iv)

> The function msidAES128DecryptedDataWithKey:keySize:() in NSData+AES.m
> uses a cryptographic encryption algorithm with an insecure mode of
> operation on line 48.
>
> The mode of operation of a block cipher is an algorithm that describes
> how to repeatedly apply a cipher's single-block operation to securely
> transform amounts of data larger than a block. Some modes of operation
> include Electronic Codebook (ECB), Cipher Block Chaining (CBC), Cipher
> Feedback (CFB), and Counter (CTR).
>
> ECB mode is inherently weak, as it produces the same ciphertext for
> identical blocks of plain text. CBC mode is vulnerable to padding
> oracle attacks. CTR mode is the superior choice because it does not
> have these weaknesses.
>
> Avoid using ECB and CBC modes of operation when encrypting data larger
> than a block. CBC mode is somewhat inefficient and poses a serious
> risk if used with SSL [1](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/tree/master#configuring-msal). Instead, use CCM (Counter with CBC-MAC)
> mode or, if performance is a concern, GCM (Galois/Counter Mode) mode
> where they are available.

```
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      key, keySize,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);
```

Example Solution - The following code uses the AES cipher with CTR mode:

```
ccStatus = CCCryptorCreateWithMode( kCCEncrypt,
    kCCModeCTR, // Uses CTR mode
    kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
    ccPKCS7Padding,
    iv,
    key,
    kCCKeySizeAES128,
    tweak,
    kCCKeySizeAES128,
    0,
    0,
    &cryptor);
```

CVE 2014-3566,
http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-3566

Comment: What is the swift tag for?

Comment: @ElTomato removed

Comment: Supposedly this is CBC: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52344
You should really generate an IV as that is definitely an attack vector on the first block

Comment: Yup, definitely CBC: https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h

With `CCCryptorCreateWithMode` you'll have to re-write the whole `CCCrypt`, unfortunately